# Logstash Filter to Parse Nested Jsons

Tags: logging, logstash, grok

Is there a way to parse nested Json objects in Logstash? The following filter works for me but doesn't parse nested json objects:

```
filter{
   json{
      { source => "message" }
   }

}
```

So if the input json is `{"Event":23 , "Fact":"Yes" , "data":{"node1":"A1", "flag":"Y"}}`

This is what it converts it to (From LogStash Logs)

```
"Event" => 23
"Fact" => "Yes"
"data" => "\"{\\\"node1\\\":"\\\A1\\\", "\\\flag\\\":"\\\Y\\\"}}
```

Comment: Have you tried a second filter->json stanza, using the new 'data' field as the source?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with Logstash 1.4.2. For me the nested field is correctly expanded.

Comment: Thats weird, I have logstash 1.4.2 as well. Are you using the same filter ? Or is there any difference?